# Optimizar parseo de JSON

Tags: python, json

Estoy tratando de accesar a los objetos de un JSON anidado, el tema es que siento que aunque funciona mi codigo, estoy utilizando mucho codigo.

La pregunta es si existe alguna manera mas simple de obtener valores de un json anidado.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import json 
import re

class interfaces:
    def __init__(self, status, code, result):
        self.status = status
        self.code = code
        self.total_count = result['total-count']
        self.count = result['count']
        self.entry = result['entry']
        self.name = result['entry']


    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_interface):
        json_dict = json.loads(json_limpio)
        return cls(**json_dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User { self.status }>'
json_interface = '''{
    "@status": "success",
    "@code": "19",
    "result": {
        "@total-count": "1",
        "@count": "1",
        "entry": [
            {
                "@name": "ethernet1/1",
                "layer3": {
                    "ndp-proxy": {
                        "enabled": "no"
                    },
                    "sdwan-link-settings": {
                        "enable": "no"
                    },
                    "ip": {
                        "entry": [
                            {
                                "@name": "192.168.254.251/24"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "lldp": {
                        "enable": "no"
                    },
                    "interface-management-profile": "MGMT"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}'''

json_limpio = re.sub('[@]', '', json_interface)
interfaces = interfaces.from_json(json_limpio)
for u in interfaces.name:
     nombre_interfaz = u["name"]
     configuracion_interfaz = u["layer3"]
     configuracion_ip = configuracion_interfaz["ip"]
     direccion_ip_lista = configuracion_ip["entry"]
     direccion_ip_diccionario = direccion_ip_lista[0]
     print(direccion_ip_diccionario["name"])
```

Siento que la parte del loop "for" es demasiado codigo y deberia haber una manera mas simple (tal vez concatenando instrucciones o algo asi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola ¿por optimizado refieres a no usar tantas variables?, si es así se haría de la siguiente forma

```
import json
import re


class interfaces:
    def __init__(self, status, code, result):
        self.status = status
        self.code = code
        self.total_count = result['total-count']
        self.count = result['count']
        self.entry = result['entry']
        self.name = result['entry']

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_interface):
        json_dict = json.loads(json_limpio)
        return cls(**json_dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User { self.status }>'


json_interface = '''{
    "@status": "success",
    "@code": "19",
    "result": {
        "@total-count": "1",
        "@count": "1",
        "entry": [
            {
                "@name": "ethernet1/1",
                "layer3": {
                    "ndp-proxy": {
                        "enabled": "no"
                    },
                    "sdwan-link-settings": {
                        "enable": "no"
                    },
                    "ip": {
                        "entry": [
                            {
                                "@name": "192.168.254.251/24"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "lldp": {
                        "enable": "no"
                    },
                    "interface-management-profile": "MGMT"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}'''


json_limpio = re.sub('[@]', '', json_interface)
interfaces = interfaces.from_json(json_limpio)
for u in interfaces.name:
    nombre_interfaz = u["name"]
    simple = u["layer3"]["ip"]["entry"][0]["name"]
    print(simple)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta, era lo que estaba buscando para optimizar mi código. Entonces si entiendo bien la lógica que usaste, con las llaves del diccionario y los índices de las listas, mencionados en la misma sentencia, puedo ir obteniendo los datos deseados. Gracias por la ayuda.